# Unlink Facebook login for Stack Exchange profile

Tags: support, login, facebook

When I first started with Stack Exchange I created a profile through a Facebook link. I am about to delete that Facebook account and was wondering if there was a way to 'unlink' my current Facebook profile and replace with another?

Or alternatively just to replace with a standard email login?

Comment: Visit https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current and "remove" your FB related login and using "add more logins ..." button to link with your standard email.